# SELECT Query with Columns stored in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in which I am getting table's column which is needed for SELECT statement in a variable with comma separated. But It is not working for me.:

**SP:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGet_Assistance_Detail]
(
  @Id int,
  @UserDesig varchar(20)  --User Desig can be 'FFR' or 'HO'
)
AS
  DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(MAX)
  SELECT @Cols = Column_Listing FROM Role_Col_Mapping WHERE Tbl_Name = 'Assistance' and Role = @UserDesig
  SELECT @Cols FROM dbo.Assistance WHERE Service_Id=(@Id)
RETURN
```

Here `Role_Col_Mapping` has fields like: `Tbl_Name`, `Role` , and `Column_Listing`. It stores data of cols allowed to any user based on his role in any table. And `Assistance` is a table which columns' data I needed to display.

I am getting wrong output. Which is cols separated by comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use dynamic SQL - something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGet_Assistance_Detail]
(
  @Id int,
  @UserDesig varchar(20)  --User Desig can be 'FFR' or 'HO'
)
AS
  DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(MAX)
  SELECT @Cols = Column_Listing FROM Role_Col_Mapping WHERE Tbl_Name = 'Assistance' and Role = @UserDesig

  DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SELECT @query = 'SELECT ' + @Cols + ' FROM CRM.dbo.Assistance WHERE Service_Id=' + cast(@Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))
  EXEC sp_executesql @query

RETURN
```

Comment: Comment EXEC and try `PRINT @query` first so see what you are getting before executing and tweak accordingly. I don't know what your `@cols` are, maybe there are commas at the end or beginning that need to be removed

Comment: Data is like this: *Service_Id,Request_Id,Vat_Tin_No,Bill_Invoice_Date,Created_Date,Entry_Done_By,Modified_Date,Executed_Date* No error in data but still facing the same problem.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4366 - Looking fine in example, please double check if you made any mistakes and/or  post your exact query so it can be checked